# R - Aggregate by outcome

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have a tibble like so:

```
tibble(
  type = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
  place = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
)
```

How can I aggregate it to get a tibble like so:

```
tibble(
  place = c(1, 2),
  n_A = c(3, 0),
  n_B = c(2, 2)
)
```

Comment: In base R, `aggregate(type~place, dat, FUN=table)` does a fine job with a data.frame. It looks like you're looking for a 'verse answer, though. Actually, you'd want `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(type~place, dat, FUN=table))` to return a more useful object (avoiding a matrix column).

Comment: If you want a tabled output, why not just use a `table`? `table(dat$type, dat$place)`

Comment: `df1%>%mutate(type=paste0("n_",type))%>%
 reshape2::dcast(place~type,length,value.var = "place")%>%
 as_tibble()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` way. Don't really need to include `B` in `replace_na` for this example since we know there are no `B = NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- tibble(type = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
              place = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))

df1 %>% 
  group_by(place, type) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  spread(type, n) %>% 
  replace_na(list(A = 0, B = 0)) %>% 
  rename(n_A = A, n_B = B)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  place   n_A   n_B
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    1.    3.    2.
2    2.    0.    2.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `table`

```
table(df1$place,df1$type)

    A B
  1 3 2
  2 0 2
```